# How to add rowClassName to a particular row in antd table on onClick of the row and not after onMouseLeave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `antd` `table` to display the information and I want to apply the `class` to the particular row when I click on it.
Currently its applying the class when I move the mouse out of the row after clicking it.
please consider this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-aryabhata-03yv2?file=/src/App.js) for the code.
the the background color of the row is changing when I move the mouse out of the row after clicking on it.
I want it change as soon as I click on it.
Also when I sort any column the background color for that column is being removed, how can I avoid that?
Any solution, reference or hint is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The background color is working as you have intended. The problem is that you are hovering on the row aswell which is changing the color. Try using a table that does not have the :hover functionality.

Comment: thank you, I thought applying another class will supersede the default styles, I need to work with antd table for some reasons but I worked it around by suppressing the css of the library on hover of a row

Answer (score 1):

The problem was even after applying another class the default styles for `hover` are still being applied, I had to suppress the default styles for `hover` on a row, for that I added this style for that particular `antd` `css class` in my `App.css`

```
.ant-table-tbody > tr.ant-table-row:hover > td {
  background: unset;
}
```

is what I did.